# Burning music on to cd that already has a photo

Tags: cd

I have a couple of questions.

1. If a cd already had music or photos saved on it then would it ask you to name the cd or does this option only come up if the cd is blank?
2. If a cd already has a photo saved on it can you then save music on to the cd at a later date?

Comment: It’s difficult to tell what’s actually the state of the CD. Windows has an “inbox” of sorts for files to put on a CD. They files will appear when browsing the (empty) CD-R/RW, but are not actually burnt onto the CD. A screenshot of the File Explorer window (this is Windows, right?) would be great. (You cannot add images inline now, but higher-rep users can fix that later.) // Also note that IIRC Windows cannot create mixed-mode CDs, containing both CD Digital Audio and computer data.

Comment: Aside from the "finalized" and/or CD-R vs CD-RW issues, be aware that optical media can be used in either a "computer" (aka "data") mode or a "media" mode (e.g. CD for music or DVD for video).  Presumably a CD that has a photo is in "computer" mode, and if you were able to write an audio file to the CD, then those files would only be accessible when the CD is mounted with a computer.  A CD player would not recognize or play music from such a CD.

Answer (score 0):

CD-ROM's cannot be written to, so I'm assuming you we are talking about the writable kind.

There exists 2 kinds of writable cd's. CD-R and CD-RW. In order to use CD-RW's you also need a CD-RW capable burner. CD-RW burners can also burn CD-R, but not the other way around.

The process for CD-R and CD-RW are almost the same with one exception. A CD-R can only be formatted once, and a CD-RW can be formatted multiple times. (Note, a CD-RW drive can only format a CD-R once. The disk itself is different for the rewritable (CD-RW) kind to allow formatting multiple times.

The process of using these is as follows:

1. **Format the disk:** In order to use the CD-R, you need to format the disk to prepare writing to it. This also gives the disk a label.
2. **Create a session:** You then create a session on the disk that will become a placeholder for the files or music.
3. **Writing to the disc:** You then write the actual files or music to the disk.
4. **Closing the session:** The session is closed and the files or music can be used by a CD Writer.

At this point, the disk can be used, but only by cd writers. You can repeat steps 2-4 many times until the cd is full.

5. **Finalize the disc:** The table of content is written for the disc which makes the content readable by regular CD drives and cd players.

If step 5 is performed, steps 2-4 cannot be performed anymore.

If the disk is a CD-R, you cannot format the disk again either, and the content is permanent. With a CD-RW, you can format the disk and start over though. The disk will be emptied though.

So with this information, lets answer your questions:

> If a cd already had music or photos saved on it then would it ask you to name the cd or does this option only come up if the cd is blank?

You give the cd a label on format, which is the first action you perform before being able to write to the disk, and its only something you can do once. So if the cd has music of photos, whatever the label was, it remains, even if blank.

> If a cd already has a photo saved on it can you then save music on to the cd at a later date?

If its a CD-R and the cd was not finalized, yes, you can add more music and photos to the cd at a later date. If its CD-RW, yes, always, but if the disk was finalized, you need to first copy the content of the disk locally, format it, then add all the files back plus whatever you want to add.

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity but does that mean if the cd asked me to enter a name then it must have been blank as it would only ask before the cd has something saved on to it?

Comment: Yes, if it asks for a name, it wants to format it. This means the drive thinks the disk is empty. If it is not supposed to be empty, then either the drive can't understand the disk, or the disk is damaged and no longer working. If the latter is the case, then the format would fail too unless CD-RW.

Comment: Also, if someone else attempted to burn the files for you, and they used Windows Explorer, its possible they dragged the files onto the disk, which showed them semi-transparent files, but they never actually clicked burn, so the disk remains empty at that point. If they insert that disk into their burner, it would show the files again as semi-transparent though, but only once they become fully visible, means the files are there.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing (sorry) so if I want to have a cd that plays in a CD player it can’t have any photos on it?

Comment: An Audio CD that you want to be playing in a normal cd player can work, All data must be written first, which becomes track 1, then track 2 and higher can be music tracks. Most modern cd players will detect this and automatically skip track 1. Older ones will play track one as if it were music, and you'll hear noise instead. For best compatibility, the cd should be written in one go then finalized.